# Minha modal não carrega

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema em apresentar uma modal de sucesso após clicar em um btn.

```
if ('@ViewBag.Mensagem' != '') {
    $(function () {
        $('#ModalSucesso').modal('toggle');
        $('#ModalSucesso').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
    });
} else {
    $(function () {
        $('#ModalSucesso').modal('hide');
    });
    }


</script>
```

E minha modal:

```
<div id="ModalSucesso" class="modal fade success" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
                <p>@ViewBag.Mensagem</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick=" location.href = '@Url.Action("DocumentoCadastro", "SecretariaExecutiva")' ">Ok </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ao entrar no console, é apresentado o seguinte erro:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)**

Inclusive, ele também aparece este erro:

**matrix.tables.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).uniform is not a function
    at HTMLDocument. (matrix.tables.js:10)
    at j (jquery.js:3137)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3249)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3455)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:3496)**

Já fiz quase de tudo para tentar resolver este problema, sou novo no javascript e ainda tenho bastante dificuldades.

Comment: O navegador achou o recurso mas não tem permissão para acessar o mesmo. Você vai ter que passar algum login válido que tenha acesso para DocumentoCadastro e SecretariaExecutiva

Comment: Então, o id do meu usuário no banco está atrelado a esta role, inclusive eu estou conseguindo executar o meu programa normalmente, ele só não carrega a modal.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando frameworks de Front-end como o [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/), você facilita muito a criação de páginas. O bootstrap possui componentes de modal muito simples de ser implementado, como você pode ver [neste exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/CedricDev/mk20yhus/1/), como também na própria [documentação do bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/). Daí utilizando apenas código HTML você pode exibir a mensagem que quiser, incluindo-a no corpo das *Divs* do modal.

**Outra opção:**

Se você quiser utilizar seu código revise o trecho `if ('@ViewBag.Mensagem' != '')` para capturar a mensagem da tag *P*, pode não estar sendo utilizado corretamente. pois você trata a mensagem `@ViewBag.Mensagem` como uma string pura e não necessariamente como o valor contido dentro de *Mensagem*.

Para fazer a condição poderia capturar o valor do texto da tag P:

```
var valorDaDiv = $("#MensagemModal").text();
if (valorDaDiv != '') {
//Seu código aqui
}
```

e no HTML utilizar:

```
<p id="MensagemModal">@ViewBag.Mensagem</p>
```

Para boas práticas utilizar ferramentas consolidadas no mercado gera produtividade no seu desenvolvimento, para javascript o [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) é altamente difundido!